# Cannot login with the StackExchange OpenID Endpoint

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid

I'd like to allow users on my site to authenticate via StackExchange account.
[This page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/) says SE OpenID endpoint should be https://openid.stackexchange.com, but I can't log in to any site using this endpoint. On the same sites, the Google OpenID endpoint works fine.

Are there any problems or limitations with SE OpenID provider?

Comment: when you say "any site" which sites are you referring to, specifically? We've tested it with a number of large, popular sites that support OpenID and it works.

Comment: I've tried it from http://openid-consumer.appspot.com. It fails.

Comment: http://www.clearbits.net/ fails too.

Comment: I can confirm that openid-consumer.appspot.com fails. It says 'Login Cancelled'.

Comment: @Andrei Can't reproduce a problem on Clearbits.net, just signed up for a new account using SE OpenID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearbits.net seems to fail for purely internal reasons.  If you create a new account with an OpenID everything seems fine; the whole exchange works properly from our end so far as I can tell.

After a brief exchange with Andrew Arnott (author of [dotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)), it was found that openid-consumer.appspot.com is non-compliant with the OpenID spec; claiming to sign fields it does not actually send.  It is impossible to securely complete authentication, so we send them an error (the cause of the "Login cancelled" message).

---

We only really care to support well written OpenID relying parties, such as...

- Ourselves (more generally, anybody using dotNetOpenAuth semi-competently)
- Disqus
- Typepad